# Rails Single Table Inheritance: How to override the value written to the type field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, single-table-inheritance

In my system I have STI already defined. `Dog` inherits from `Animal`, in the `animals` table there's a `type` column with the value `"Dog"`.

Now I want to have `SpecialDog` inherit from dog, just to modify the behavior slightly in some special case. The data is still the same. I need all the queries that are run through `SpecialDog` to return the values in the database that have the type `Dog`.

My problem is that since I have a `type` column, rails appends `WHERE "animals"."type" IN ('SpecialDog')` to my query so I cannot get to the original `Dog` entries. So what I want is to somehow override the value rails uses when it accesses the database through `SpecialDog` to behave like `Dog`.

**Is there a way to override the value rails use for the type column?**

Comment: Are you saving any dogs as SpecialDog? Or are all dogs Dog, but they're sometimes special?

Comment: In the database they are always 'Dog'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It kind of feels like bad practice to do it this way, but the below code should work as far as I can tell.

```
def self.sti_name
  "Dog"
end
```

My other suggestion is to not have `SpecialDog` inherit from `Dog`, if possible.

Comment: not working anymore???

i have the same case, ruby 2.0.0, rails 3.0.10, no success using it.